# Company wants to "catch up" after an interview. What does that mean?

Tags: interviewing, follow-up, terminology

I did a phone interview last week with a tech company for a mobile engineering position, and they called me in for an in-person interview the next day.

The phone interview was with an HR person, and the in-person interview was with their mobile engineering director and 2 lead mobile engineers. The HR person was there at the very beginning, but he basically made introductions and left when we got to technical questions. He told me in advance that that would happen. The interview went incredibly well, and I felt that I did a great job answering their questions and speaking with the interviewers.

I was given a tour of the office after, and they said they would be in touch early next week (that's this week).

I got an email today from the HR person mentioned earlier asking to "catch up" tomorrow. What does that mean?

Comment: it means they're going to call you and let you know how the interview went

Comment: Is there some reason you think this means something other than that they want to catch up??

Comment: That depends on what you think "catch up" means, AakashM. It's just vapid jargon for meeting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a good thing.  If the company wasn't interested in hiring you, they'd cut you loose and tell you straight out.  They wouldn't want to "Catch up" only to let you down hard.

At this point, given the timing, I'd probably expect two things.

- They will present you an offer (Best case)
- They will schedule a second interview with a higher level manager/vice president/etc.  In your case, it could be the director's manager.  Now that you've passed the initial test with the engineers, they have the final call on whether to hire you.

Comment: Still, I'd advise OP to not count their chickens before they hatch. I once played phone tag with a company recruiter after an interview I thought went very well, only to find they just wanted to talk about why they weren't making an offer..

Comment: I don't think companies are too quick to cut you loose unless you're definitely not qualified and/or they've filled the position. Every time someone wants time to think about an offer, others are waiting for a call.

Answer (score 3):

If you're invited to "catch up" or have a (short) follow-up meeting or chat with a recruiter or HR, that's typically going to be a call to give you feedback about the interview and tell you whether or not they'll give you an offer or what the next steps in the interview process will be, if any.

It could be positive or negative. The only way to find out is to have the call.

If the feedback is positive, they may also ask some administrative questions like what your notice period is or when you'd be able to start.